# Piwik + uWSGI setup

Tags: nginx, php, uwsgi, piwik

I have a problem setting up uWSGI+piwik using nginx. My configuration follows this [blog entry](http://metz.gehn.net/2013/02/running-anything-on-nginx-with-uwsgi/). My uwsgi ini file looks like this

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = php
chown-socket = www-data:www-data
uid = piwik
gid = piwik
processes = 1
```

and my nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/piwik;
    server_name my.domain.com;
    index piwik.php;
    # For administrative access
    location = /index.php {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_modifier1 14;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/app/piwik/socket;
        allow 127.0.0.1; # only via ssh tunnel
        deny all;
    }
    # For public access
    location = /piwik.php {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_modifier1 14;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/app/piwik/socket;
    }
    # Any other attempt to access PHP files is forbidden
    location ~* ^.+\.php$ {
        return 403;
    }
    # Redirect to the root if attempting to access a txt file.
    location ~* (?:DESIGN|(?:gpl|README|LICENSE)[^.]*|LEGALNOTICE)(?:\.txt)*$ {
        return 302 /;
    }
    # Disallow access to several helper files.
    location ~* \.(?:bat|html?|git|ini|sh|svn[^.]*|txt|tpl|xml)$ {
        return 404;
    }
    # Disallow access to directories
    location ~ ^/(config|core|lang|misc|tmp)/ {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

The log file contains this, which indicates the error:

```
Tue Aug 25 15:34:34 2015 - PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The configuration file {/var/www/piwik/config/config.ini.php} has not been found or could not be read.' in /var/www/piwik/core/Application/Kernel/EnvironmentValidator.php:64
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/piwik/core/Application/Kernel/EnvironmentValidator.php(45): Piwik\Application\Kernel\EnvironmentValidator->checkConfigFileExists('/var/www/piwik/...', false)
#1 /var/www/piwik/core/Application/Environment.php(185): Piwik\Application\Kernel\EnvironmentValidator->validate()
#2 /var/www/piwik/core/Application/Environment.php(94): Piwik\Application\Environment->validateEnvironment()
#3 /var/www/piwik/piwik.php(56): Piwik\Application\Environment->init()
#4 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/piwik/core/Application/Kernel/EnvironmentValidator.php on line 64
[pid: 23656|app: -1|req: -1/3] 109.90.112.120 () {36 vars in 567 bytes} [Tue Aug 25 15:34:34 2015] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 58 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 1 headers in 78 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

When I open the page with a browser a log entry like this is generated and I see a blank page (makes sense with 0 generated bytes). The problem is that the expected Piwik install script does not start. Instead an exception is thrown. I tried to change `/var/www/piwik/core/Application/Kernel/EnvironmentValidator.php` to manually trigger the setup but did not succeed. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are questing /piwik.php (if you requesting /, /piwik.php is marked as default). /piwik.php is the tracker. You have to request /index.php before and use web administration interface to produce the config file.